# woocommerce product countdown not showing in variable product?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a E-commerce site using wordpress,woocommerce. After I can add products of different categories. the problem is product countdown works fine in (Simple Product ) by not showing in (Variable product).

Like...
[image]